# TYPO3: Don't clear cache after editing content

Tags: php, caching, typo3

When you edit content on a page, the TYPO3 frontend cache for this page is automatically cleared after saving the content element.

This results in massive performance problems, e.g. when you have hundreds of news records and edit the news detail page.

Is there a way to disable this for specific pages?

Answer (score 2, accepted):

This might be possible with a DataHandler hook (this class registers pages whose caches must be flushed after an edit) but I certainly would not recommend doing this. Normally you *want* the cache to be cleared if you make a change to a page.

Comment: I thought perhaps there is a setting in Page TS config, but this seems to be the only way.

Answer (score 0):

The problem is the complete cache clearing.
If you add / edit one news the detail-view of all other news (normaly) is not involved.

A page TSconfig to clear all page caches of pages where news are displayed is to wide.

tx_news therefore uses cache-tags to clear selectively.
But this could result in too less caches been cleared. (bidirectional related news, lists, ...)

If you avoid a cache clearing after adding/editing news you will have problems that your changes will not be seen in public.
Avoiding caches at all (for these pages) will drastically reduce the performance of your page.

As caches normaly are cleared after a given time anyway, you might force this in a nightly task: clear all caches and rebuild it with a crawler/spider.

Comment: I didn't talk about clearing cache after editing news, my problem is that TYPO3 automatically clears the cache after I edit content on the news detail page, e.g. the news plugin or an ad banner.

Comment: but then the caches needed to be cleared - otherwise your edit would not be included in all generated variants of the page.

Comment: But I do not want the cache to be cleared at once, in my opinion it would be (in this case) better, the cache is cleared at midnight or some other time or the cached content expires automatically after a defined time.

Comment: then you should use the tools provided to publish changes at given times. if you use workspaces you can do edits and publish them automatically at a given time.